# Having had several classes taught in English or...? Correct usage

Tags: grammar

Suppose I have a phrase like this one:

> Having had several classes taught in English, I'm familiar with the professional vocabulary

Is it correct? Can I say "classes taught" or should I say "classes that were taught"? Or maybe, given it's the Present Perfect in the first part of the sentence, I should also use the Perfect tense in the classes part of it?

Comment: The teachers *possess* the classes more than the students do, so "had classes" is misleading if you were a student ("having attended classes" is better), and you would simply say "having taught" if you were the teacher.

Answer (score 1):

The general structure is OK, but I'd suggest **taken** instead of **had**:

> Having taken several classes taught in English, I'm familiar ...

**taught in English** is a clause headed by past participle **taught**  and it is a modifier of the noun **classes**.